# Dependencies problem with AMD driver on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, amdgpu

I have downloaded this driver https://www.amd.com/fr/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5600-series/amd-radeon-rx-5600-series/amd-radeon-rx-5600-xt (Ubuntu 22.04)

```
victor@desktop:~/Téléchargements$ amdgpu-install 
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                    
Hit:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                            
Hit:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                                                          
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports-extra/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                               
Hit:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                     
Get:7 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease [2961 B]                                                          
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                     
Hit:9 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.6/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Hit:11 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.4.6 jammy InRelease
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/phoerious/keepassxc/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 2961 B in 1s (3159 B/s)                            
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.15.0-75-generic is already the newest version (5.15.0-75.82).
linux-headers-5.15.0-75-generic set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libzstd1:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable
                        Recommends: libgl1-amber-dri:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I cannot install the package:

```
victor@desktop:~/Téléchargements$ sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
 dpkg : PreDepends: libzstd1 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libzstd1 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable
 libtiff5 : Depends: libzstd1 (>= 1.3.2) but it is not installable
 util-linux : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How can I solve this problem so that I can install the driver and get OpenCL support?

Comment: No it does not answer my question, none of the solutions in these question solve my problem.